# What does this icon mean?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Please tell me what this icon means. I cloned code from GitHub, and now all classes have the icon.

[image]

In the figure the arrow shows the icon.

Comment: It has a J, so I'd say Java file, but can't find it here. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/icons-reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That icon means that the file is a java class. You do not see with a "C" (class) because you do not have that build variant selected.